# Ember.js: How can I prevent transition on dirty model with async confirmation?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a pretty common situation: there is a dirty model and I want to show a confirmation if user tries to transition to any other route.

I have something like this to work with `window.confirm` confirmation dialog:

```
var EventRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      var event = this.modelFor(this.routeName);
      if (event.get('isDirty') && !confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        transition.abort();
      } else {
        event.rollback();
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But if I want to use asynchronous confirmation (e.g. [bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com) confirmation), how can I stop transition?

I've tried to return `Ember.RSVP.Promise` but it seems that `willTransition` doesn't support promises.

So the question is **how is it possible to prevent transition to another route with async confirmation?**

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should not call your variables "event", and doubly so if they're not representing an event.

Comment: In my case it is an event entity, so it's fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `abort` to cancel/pause the transition, then with that same transition instance you can call `retry` to attempt the transition again.

In the example included I'm stopping the transition, then a second later starting it again.  You could launch your confirmation dialog and upon clicking ok/cancel use the transition object to continue the transition.

```
willTransition: function(transition){
  var self = this;
  if(!this.get('allowTransition')){
    console.log('transition abort');
    transition.abort(); 

    Em.run.later(function(){
      self.set('allowTransition', true);
      console.log('transition retry');
      transition.retry();
   }, 1000);
 }
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gefituqo/1/edit

Comment: Nice trick! (: Well, if there're no cleaner solution for this, then I'll use it. Thanks